# output batch file log to seperate directory

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file which currently output a log file by calling its extension

```
(sqlplus  @Down.sql "test" "testl") > "%~dpn0.log"
```

which outputs the log file to the same location of the batch folder.

e.g. C:\Folder1\run.bat

of course, the log file would be run.log

I would like to output the log file to a log folder.

similar to C:\Folder1\log\run.log.

Anyhelp is appreciated in pointing out hwo to do it in my source code. Thanks

Comment: You can add the path to your folder after the operator `>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...> "c:\folder1\log\%~n0.log"
```

should suffice. The trick is the `%0` means `the name of the batch`, and this can be mofified by `~letters` which may be used in any combination.

The letters that are significant are listed conveniently in the `for` documentation, accessible from

```
for /?
```

executed from the prompt.

Comment: is there a way to make it into a relative path

Comment: a relative instead of an absolute path

Comment: `.` means 'the current directory' `..` means `the parent directory to the current`.